# LineageOS : upgrade nightly to unofficial

Tags: lineageos

I have a lineageos 14.1 nightly signed (downloaded from the official website) installed on my phone. I built a 14.1 from the sources following [the official wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/Z00T/build) (tagged unofficial build). Currently I have this message saying to wipe the `/data` :

> Can't install this package on top of incompatible data. Please try
>   another package or run a factory reset

I don't understand why I should wipe my data, I thought that it was only when changing to a different ROM.

I want to know if there is a way to flash an unofficial without losing my data or why is that needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the release key is different, so a simple key migration solve it. The steps are explained [on the Wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/signing_builds.html#test-keys-to-official-or-vice-versa-1).

Comment: Could you please check [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209156/16575), Taknok? Someone had a follow-up question on yours and is asking you for a comment. Thanks!